# Able to fetch data but unable to display it in table

Tags: angularjs

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table']);
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.get = function ()
    {
    $http.get('JsonProcessor.do').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) 
        {
            $scope.rowCollection = data[0];
            console.log("Result from Database: ", data[0]); //prints value
            console.log(data[0].ID); //prints ID
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) 
        {
        });
    };
});
```

I am able to fetch data and display it in console but I wonder its not displayed inside table.

However, `ng-repeat` creates four rows in table but with no data

Html:

```
<table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Unique Id</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Doc Url</th>
            <th>Time Stamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
            <td>{{row.ID}}</td>
            <td>{{row.DATE_CREATED}}</td>
            <td>{{row.URL}}</td>
            <td>{{row.TIMESTAMP}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is `data[0]` an array?

Comment: @tymeJV I am using map key-value pairs stored in List object in the back end and sending it as json

Comment: Where is your reference to `MyController`?

Comment: @peteb `MyController` is right htere in the code

Comment: In your HTML, I don't see `MyController` being referenced like `ng-controller="MyController"` is it referenced in a parent element like a `div`?

Comment: @peteb yes it is on parent element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is coming from a service call you must use st-safe-src for smart table.

http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

```
stSafeSrc attribute
```

"If you are bringing in data asynchronously (from a remote database, restful endpoint, ajax call, etc) you must use the stSafeSrc attribute. You must use a seperate collection for both the base and safe collections or you may end up with an infinite loop."

Comment: Wow, amazing that solved the issue but its showing lot of errors in console after adding `stSafeSrc` like: `Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]` , `Error: [$rootScope:infdig]`

Comment: Ah, you probably didn't do this step "You must use a seperate collection for both the base and safe collections or you may end up with an infinite loop." In my code I followed the example fully by having this   $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.data) at the top of my controller and in my restful service response having $scope.data = results.SearchOrderResponse.orderDataX9